# Does a MessageQueue block on a send if the queue is full

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, msmq

I've been looking through the documentation on Message Queues and I can't seem to find the information I'm looking for. What I'm trying to accomplish is to log the name of a MySQL database procedure whenever it is called for the purpose of tracking how often each procedure is called. My thought was to log the name to a MessageQueue when it is called and have a service process the queue to count up the calls periodically. This is to avoid writing an additional record to the database for each procedure call. Since this is not a critical function, I would like to be able to skip the logging if the queue is full. I'm looking for the following information:

- Does MessageQueue.Send block if the queue is full?
- Does MessageQueue store message in memory or on disk? I'd like to keep this all in memory, so if the only option is to write to a file, then I don't think this is what we're looking for.

Also if I'm overlooking an easier solution here, let me know.

Comment: If all you want to do is track hit counts, and you don't need to aggregate them over a server farm or something like that, you might want to take a look at using performance counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a full queue will not block.

- Sending to a full local queue will return an exception.
- Sending to a full remote queue will discard the message, or move it to the dead letter queue, as appropriate.

MSMQ Express messages are memory-resident only. They may be written to disk when the system is under memory pressure but they are not persistent - a reboot will lose them.